# wp8 c# ApplicationSettings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

If I do this:
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["mytype"] = "x-type";
I can later find mytype-setting even if I didn't use Save-method.

Should I use Save for some reason ?

Answer (score 2):

> Data written to the IsolatedStorageSettings object is saved when the
>   application that uses the class is closed. This can occur when the
>   user closes the Web browser, refreshes a page, or browses away from
>   the page. If you want your application to write to isolated storage
>   immediately, you can call the Save method in application code.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save(v=vs.95).aspx)

Meaning that as long as you don't close your app you'll be fine, but if something happens (imagine you receive a phone call), or if you really close your app the variable will be lost. You should use the Save() method.

Comment: I think msdn text means, if I really close the app, settings object is saved automatically. Keyword is immediately.

Comment: Ok, that piece of text makes you think that way. However if you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you can see (in the bottom of the page) that:

The IsolatedStorageSettings class is not automatically saved
to disk when values are written. Saves are done in a finalizer, which is usually but **not always** run when the application shuts down. To ensure saves are actually performed we need to call the Save method after each write or set of writes.